Closing connections in AWS Glue
I am trying to extract around 500 tables from an oracle database dynamically in a loop using AWS Glue to S3. I am able to do this successfully for around 200+ tables but then it starts to fail after a certain number. The error I get is this:
An error occurred while calling o41372.getDynamicFrame. : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 22 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:935)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:700)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1041)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:89)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:732)     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:648)     at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$connectionProperties$5(JDBCUtils.scala:1120)     at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$connectWithSSLAttempt$2(JDBCUtils.scala:1071)     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$connectWithSSLAttempt$1(JDBCUtils.scala:1071)     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectWithSSLAttempt(JDBCUtils.scala:1071)     at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:1116)     at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties$lzycompute(JDBCUtils.scala:822)     at 

I believe it is related to reaching the max number of connections that oracle can handle and oracle is forcefully closing all the next connections that are being sent to it. Is there any way I can close these connections in AWS Glue before I open a new one and extract the next table.
My code snippet sample:
def initial_extract_data_to_s3(CONNECTION,DATABASE,SCHEMA,TABLE):
    try:
        data_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                                    connection_type = "oracle",
                                    connection_options = {
                                        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
                                        "dbtable": f"{schema_name}.{table_name}",
                                        "sampleQuery":src_query,
                                        "connectionName": f"{connection}",
                                        "hashexpression":f"{partition_key}",
                                        "hashpartitions":"12",
                                    },
                                    transformation_ctx = "data_df")

        
        data_df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "snappy").parquet(f"s3://{db_name}/{schema_name}/{table_name}")
            
    except Exception as exc: 
        print(exc)

#Calling the above function below:

for row in df.collect():
    try:
        connection = row['CONNECTION']
        db_name = row['DATABASE']
        schema_name = row['SCHEMA']
        table_name = row['TABLE']

        # Call your functions here
        initial_extract_data_to_s3(CONNECTION,DATABASE,SCHEMA,TABLE)

    except Exception as e:
        continue  # Continue to the next table

Is there a better way to handle this other than having to break up the jobs for every 200 tables and extract the 500 tables in a single job instead?

Have you tried to clear the data_df object at the end of initial_extract_data_to_s3? Maybe there are some references still on place : use 'del data_df' right after data_df.repartition(1).write.....

Hi ! Thank you I will try and let you know how it goes

Hi @Bogdan, I did try the method you suggested however it did not work. I have researched more into this topic and it seems like it isn't possible to close connections explicitly in Spark. Are there any other alternatives?

If the issue is the size of the connections, you can set a timeout for each connection by adjusting the connection string directly, where you specify parameters like the host and port. This approach might help by closing some of the connections.
